# how to read input from barcode scanner?

Tags: vb.net

I have two text box that need two retrieve data from scanning the barcode. Currently, i need to scan the barcode two times. So, i want to scan the barcode only once. So, can someone help me to do this? Here, currently my code.

```
Private Sub TextScanPartNo_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextScanPartNo.KeyPress
    TextScanPartNo.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
    Dim ProdDate As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/d/yyyy")
    Dim s As String

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        s = TextScanPartNo.Text.Split(New Char() {"|c"})(2)
        TextScanPartNo.Text = s
        If cls_PICS.get_PartNo(Trim(TextScanPartNo.Text)) = False Then
            'TextBoxMOQ.ReadOnly = True
            'CheckBox1.Enabled = False
            Dim SQL_str As String =
    "SELECT * " &
    "FROM [mastersetup] where PartNo ='" & TextScanPartNo.Text & "'"


            Dim adLWS As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL_str, cnPICS)
            Dim dsLWS As New DataSet
            adLWS.Fill(dsLWS, "BOXID1")

            LWS_CONT = dsLWS.Tables("BOXID1").Rows.Count


            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To LWS_CONT - 1
                TextBoxMOQ.Text = dsLWS.Tables("BOXID1").Rows(i)("MOQ").ToString
                TextBox3.Text = dsLWS.Tables("BOXID1").Rows(i)("Inspection").ToString

            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("Please insert Standard Box Quantity")

        End If
        If cls_PICS.get_ExistingSequenceNoOld(TextScanPartNo.Text, TextBoxMOQ.Text, TextVendorID.Text) = True Then
            'If cls_PICS.get_ExistingSequenceNoOld(TextScanPartNo.Text) = True Then
            cls_PICS.BOXIDRunningNo(cls_PICS.BoxEnd(0))
            TextStart.Text = cls_PICS.NewBox
        Else
            TextStart.Text = "A00001"

        End If
        TextBoxDelivery.Focus()

    End If



End Sub

   Private Sub TextBoxDelivery_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBoxDelivery.KeyPress
    TextBoxDelivery.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
    Dim s As String

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        s = TextBoxDelivery.Text.Split(New Char() {"|c"})(5)
        TextBoxDelivery.Text = s
        TextBoxPQty.Text = (Int(Val(TextBoxDelivery.Text) / Val(TextBoxMOQ.Text))).ToString
        TextBoxPQty.Focus()

    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have to scan the barcode two times? Why can't you just save the scanned barcode data in a variable and use it later?

Comment: @vintastic can you give me an example how to do it?